# Error : Could not find or load main class

Tags: maven-2, javac

I have compiled the maven project using "mvn install" command.
test.jar file is created in the path of /project/target/test.jar.

I am just trying run the the command "sudo java -jar test.jar".
Getting below error

**Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.xx.controller.MainApp.**

Could you please help to resolve this error.

I am new this technology(maven).

Note: This code I am compiling in ubuntu 20.04 64 bit machine.

Comment: Issue is resolved after reinstalling JDK 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved after reinstalling JDK 8.